# A connectivity-preserving function from a connected set onto an interval

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, connectedness

Let $C$ be a connected set in the plane and $I$ the unit interval. Call a function $f$ from $C$ onto $I$ **Connectivity-preserving** if the following is true for every subset $I'\subseteq I$:

- If $I'$ has zero length then $f^{-1}(I')$ has zero area.
- If $I'$ is connected (i.e. an interval) then $f^{-1}(I')$ is connected.

In what cases does a connectivity-preserving function exists?

If $C$ is convex, then a connectivity-preserving function always exists: just position $C$ above $I$ and project each point of $C$ to the point of $I$ just below it:
[image]

(this function is even convexity-preserving).

But if $C$ is not convex, the simple vertical projection is not connectivity-preserving:
[image]

Is there another way to find a connectivity-preserving function when $C$ is simply-connected? path-connected? connected?

Comment: Must projections be linear? In that case, a "spiral" is simply connected but does not allow such a projection

Comment: Projections do not have to be linear.

Comment: @Erel Segal-Halevi I think Hagen von Eitzen was asking you to define the term projection.

Comment: For any given $C$ there are only two projections *onto* the unit interval. Are you sure you did not want a little bit more freedom in your definition, e.g., asking under what conditions on $C$ there exists any kind of projection on any kind of line such that inverse images of intervals are connected.

Comment: @Justpassingby I mixed things up.  I need any function from $C$ onto the unit interval, that maps zero-area subsets of $C$ to zero-length subses of $I$ and positive-area subsets of $C$ to positive-length subsets of $I$. I edited the question to clarify this issue.

Comment: @Erel Segal-Halevi Are you aware that even an ordinary orthogonal projection, such as in your drawings, maps most line intervals (an important class of zero-area sets) to positive-length subsets of $I$?

Comment: @Justpassingby Thanks again. The first condition indeed does not make sense. Only the second does. The function should map positive-area subsets of $C$ to positive-length subsets of $I$.

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi Are we assuming that $f$ is continuous?

Comment: I believe it would be useful to think of $f$ not as a projection to an interval, but as a scalar field over $C$ all of whose level sets are connected. For example, the global minimum and global maximum must be attained over connected sets, and there should be no other critical points.

Comment: @Rahul If we assume that projections must be continuous and if we add some kind of *a priori* (pathwise?) connectedness condition on $C$ then the requirement that $f^{-1}(I')$ be connected for all intervals $I'$ can probably be softened to your connected contour condition, i.e., $f^{-1}(i)$ connected for $0\leq i\leq1.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Incomplete answer, I may get back when I understand these sets better)*

Connectedness is a necessary condition because we can take $I'=I.$ I will enumerate a few sufficient conditions but I have not been able to unify them. Let us call the property $P,$ so $P(C)$ is an abbreviation for the existence of a connectivity-preserving map $f$ from $C\subset\mathbb R^2$ to $I.$

Open and star-shaped is sufficient: if $c\in C$ and all the lines $\{[cx]|x\in C\}$ are contained in $C$ then the map

$$f:C\to I:x\mapsto\frac1\pi\arg(x-c)$$

is connectivity-preserving ($c$ itself can be mapped to any argument because $C$ contains an open disk around $c$).

More generally any simply connected open proper subset of the plane is conformally equivalent to an open disk (by the [Riemann mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_mapping_theorem)). The conformal equivalence (known as "Riemann mapping") maps positive areas to positive areas and preserves connectedness of subsets (being a homeomorphism), and therefore preserves property $P.$

The whole plane has property $P,$ as well.

$P(\emptyset).$ More generally any connected set of zero area has property $P:$ use the constant map to a single point of $I.$

An open disk with the centre removed has property $P:$ the distance from the centre is connectivity-preserving. Thus simple connectedness is not a necessary condition. Any open subset of the plane that is conformally equivalent to an open disk with the centre removed also has property $P.$

If $P(C)$ and there exists a homeomorphism $C\to D$ that preserves thinness of subsets (i.e., having zero area) then $P(D).$ Conformal equivalences are examples of such homeomorphisms.

Let $C$ be an open disk with a finite number of points $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ removed. We shall construct a projection $f$ as follows. Draw a finite number of line segments inside $C$ that make up a tree structure $T$ (no loops) and that connect the missing points with the boundary of $C.$ The tree structure must be connected inside $C,$ i.e., the missing points are end nodes of the tree.

Then $T$ is a closed connected subset of $C$ having zero area and such that its complement $T\setminus C$ is an open simply connected subset of the plane. Take a projection $g$ on the complement with the particular property that it has limit $1$ near the boundary. Extend $g:T\setminus C\to I$ to $f:C\to I$ by assigning the constant $1$ to all points of $T.$ The extended mapping $f$ is a projection of $C$ because it agrees with the original $g$ almost everywhere and because the inverse of any nontrivial interval $I'$ containing $1$ also contains connected subsets of $C\setminus T$ arbitrarily close to the closed set $T.$

Now for a class of counterexamples.

If there exists a point $c\in C$ such that $C-\{c\}$ has at least $3$ connected components with nonzero area, then $P(C)$ is false. To see this consider a hypothetical connectivity-preserving map $f,$ set $r=f(c)$ and observe that each of the $3$ components has at least one point that is mapped to a value different from $r.$ This implies that the inverse image of $[0,r)$ or the inverse image of $(r,1]$ is disconnected.

More generally $P(C)$ is false if there are a finite number of points $\{c_1,\ldots,c_n\}$ such that $C-\{c_1,\ldots,c_n\}$ has at least $n+2$ components of nonzero area. Think of certain planar graph representations where the vertices are points and the edges are disjoint nonsingular curves between them, and then blow up some of the vertex points to become little balls.

Comment: Interesting.  The homeomorphism condition seems the most general; can you elaborate on why this condition is true?

Comment: Unfortunately it is probably false. I was incorrectly assuming that homeomorphisms of subsets of the plane preserve null sets.

Comment: About the star-shape: where does the point $c$ itself go?

Comment: Again, this is not correct in general. I will think about whether some of my answer can be saved, or otherwise simply withdraw it so that the question may attract new attention.

Comment: Thanks! So being open and simply-conneced is sufficient but not necessary, right?

Comment: That is correct. I think that punching out a finite number of holes is OK but the proof might get hairy.

Comment: And, if I am not mistaken, the pre-image of an interval will also be simply-connected  (because the inverse mapping is also conformal), right?

Comment: I do not understand that last remark, especially the word also. Simple connectedness is *not* a necessary condition so what are you referring to?

Comment: My conjecture is:   if $C$ is open and simply-connected, then there exists a  connectivity-preserving function $f: C\to I$ such that, if $I' \subseteq I$ is connected, then $f^{-1}(I')$ is **simply**-connected (and not only connected). Is this true?

Comment: That sounds reasonable. I think that if $C$ is not the whole plane then $f$ can be constructed as the composition of the conformal equivalence from the Riemann mapping theorem with the linear function that maps points of the open unit disk to $(x+1)/2$ (where $x$ is horizontal coordinate).

Comment: Thank you! This is a very helpful answer.

Comment: How can I cite you in a paper (by what name)?

Comment: Either "an anonymous user on math.stackexchange" or "user Justpassingby on math.stackexchange" will be fine, thanks. If you post the arXiv reference here I can copy it into the answer.